# Cast to std::string in debug visualizer (autoexp.dat)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

I have a class which stores a `std::string*` in a field `void* data`, and would like VS2010's debugger to show the string as preview (yes, I need it to be a void pointer).

When I tried to access the std::string fields as a starting point, I already failed. The following doesn't seem to work, and Visual Studio just shows the pointer `data`.

```
preview (
    #if ( $c.data != 0 ) (
        (((std::basic_string<char>*)$c.data))->_Myres
    ) #else (
        ""
    )
)
```

Is there any way to do this, or any place where detailed error messages for autoexp.dat parsing can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
std::basic_string<char>
```

with

```
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

It works for my case.

If you write a string variable in source code as

```
std::string foo;
```

Then, you'll see in locals window of Visual Studio like this:

```
name | value | type
foo  | ""    | std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

I guess the debugger needs this specific type for cast expression.